# can't open web page on my virtual lamp server ubuntu 12.04

Tags: php, mysql, ubuntu, lamp

i can't open one php script on my virtual ubuntu 12.04 lamp server, i tried at an online host and it works fine but at home didn't work.

what i already did:
 i intall php 5.4 like the online host
 change permisions on folder 
change user folder
install php 7 (but the scripts tell php 5.4-5.5)

and i get this error page when i try to open: The requested URL /loja/login was not found on this server.

and the log apache tell : 
[client 192.168.0.10] File does not exist: /var/www/script/login
"GET /loja/ HTTP/1.1" 307 769 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36"
192.168.0.10 - - [02/Apr/2017:00:12:23 -0300] "GET /loja/login HTTP/1.1" 404 502 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36""

what is wrong on my lamp server? onlines hosts works very well.
the script: https://mega.nz/#!dpskSCDS!vmlxWXVjByV67wv41DO8MqDMPgfjBpxxj_p7uoxmfjQ

Comment: Possible that you've to adjust owner or access-rights to some files locally.
If you upload files by FTP the owner is mostly automatically the FTP-user, therefore you never remark that problem on the server.

Comment: it's virtual ubuntu server on my pc

Comment: Probably you've some mess with paths in the scripts.
I suppose you don't have a folder "/loja/" on root-level of your Ubuntu-Installation.

Answer (score 0):

Hi please add your php files on your htdocs folder it's **/opt/lampp/htdocs**

also do this

**This will change the ownership of the /opt/lampp/htdocs/ to you:**

```
sudo chown username:groupname /opt/lampp/htdocs
```

**Example : (My username is test and my group name is also test)**

```
sudo chown test:test /opt/lampp htdocs
```

**This will change the folder's permissions to be read, write and executed by you:**

```
sudo chmod 777 /opt/lampp/htdocs
```

Comment: i already did this, changing the permissions to 777 and the user/group on /var/www/

Comment: setting rights to 777 is very uncommon and only done by beginners.
It's unsecure and shouldn't be considered at all.

Comment: change to 700 so it's safer

Comment: restart apache and see how it goes